# Tab Content Does Not Refresh After First Click of Like Button

Tags: facebook, tabs, refresh, facebook-like, page-refresh

I've implemented a very simple "like guard" for a facebook tab, and am running into an issue with my test users.  Multiple testers are reporting that when they open a tab and click the "like" button, they do not always get a page refresh (so the like guard does not disappear until they do a manual reload).  This is using facebook's like button at the top of the page, not one I've coded up myself.

As a sanity check, I enabled some simple logging on my server and have been able to recreate the issue - I hit "like" or "unlike" but there seems to be no request made to my index.php page, so definitely no refresh happening.

I'm aware of this old bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228778937218386  but this one seems different.  For starters, after the first click of the "like" button, if I just continue clicking unlike/like/.... then the refresh happens automatically, as expected.  What's especially weird is that **if I reload the page** after the first failed refresh, the refreshes start working again as expected, ie the first update to my like status triggers a page refresh.

Some possibly (?) relevant info:

1. My Tab is part of a test page, and is unpublished
2. I am only using http hosting for the tab content, since my https isn't set up yet
3. So far I've just tested with other admins - so maybe user role affects this?

Curious to see if anyone has run into this issue before.

Comment: hmm, the only way I've found to recreate this issue 100% of the time is to visit the tab after I've "Liked" the page. When first viewing the tab, if I click the unlike button, I get no refresh 100% of the time (but subsequent likes/unlikes do trigger the refresh).  This is happening in IE9 and firefox, so not likely a browser issue...

Answer (score 1):

Finally settled this problem, sharing in case others run into the same issue:

My confusion was caused by where I created/assigned my testers.  I made a dummy community page to host the tab I was building and I added all my testers to **the test community page**.  I realized that the only users not getting the weird refresh problems were those testers who I had also added as admin/testers for the app itself.  Apparently, adding them as testers to your community page is not enough, and rather than giving you some kind of warning when they view your tabs, testers just get this buggy refresh behavior.